# PSD Form Login to html

Tags: html, forms, photoshop, psd

I have a PSD file with this login form: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3076951/loginForm.jpg
I want to have an HTML from the PSD, can you tell me if the only way to do that is to use Photoshop? I don't like that photoshop uses a table to render the form.
What is the best way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Personally, I would make the login form without any images, using only CSS and HTML. It would be more efficient and scalable.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it yet,
But heard from friends about this one
http://www.psdtoweb.de/ (this is free). And also have a look at this [page](http://www.webhostingbillboarders.com/design/free-online-tools-for-psd-to-htmlcss-conversion/)

Answer (score 0):

You could for instance slice the image in Photoshop to HTML and images, slicing the image's form fields to be used as background images. There's [a tutorial for image slicing](http://psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-tips/slices-in-photoshop/).

I'd suggest marking up the fields themselves by hand.